# Filtering by year using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, leaflet

I have a leaflet interactive map and I want to filter out geojson data by year.  I want to use underscore.js to filter.  The field in question is "info_city", which contains year entries.  My filter function is as follows:

```
function filterByYear(data){
    console.log("filtering")
    console.log(data)
    f = _.where(data, {info_date : "2006"}); 
    console.log(f) 
    return f;
}
```

Here is the way my geojson is set up:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "info_address": "Insitut fur Rontgendiagnostik, Universitatsklinikum Wurzburg, Oberdurrbacher Str 6",
    "info_city": "Wuerzburg",
    "info_state": "Germany",
    "info_zip": 97080,
    "info_country": "",
    "info_notes": "Unsure of how to format the German address",
    "info_lastName": "Bley",
    "info_maidenName": "",
    "info_firstName": "Thorsten",
    "info_middleName": "",
    "info_intern": "",
    "info_resident": "",
    "info_fellow": "",
    "info_fellowshipSection": "",
    "info_honoraryFellow": "",
    "info_formerFaculty": "fac",
    "info_facultySection": "Thoracic Imaging",
    "info_residencyBegin": "",
    "info_residencyEnd": "",
    "info_fellowshipBegin": "",
    "info_fellowshipEnd": "",
    "info_institution": "",
    "info_position": "Visiting faculty",
    "info_count": 1,
    "info_resDate": 1900,
    "info_felDate": 1900,
    "info_date": 2009,
    "info_status": "fac"
  },
```

Should underscore.js automatically read "info_date" as a one of the fields?  Or, do I need to do some prep and isolate the info_date field as a variable?

Comment: if you prepare a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem, I guarantee the users here will show you the necessary fix straight away.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the following:

```
f = _.filter(data, o => _.isMatch(o.properties, {info_date : 2009}))
```

This way, `{info_date : 2009}` can be extended to any json object one wants to match.

Comment: Ryan- Thanks- I tried this, but again when I console log (f) it returns an empty array even though the years in question should be returned.

Comment: is your `data` an array?

Comment: Ryan - I think so, in my original post I included a sample of one of the objects in my geojson- each feature has those given properties, which includes the info_date field that I'm interested in filtering.

Comment: Yep, when I console.log (data) it's an array of 181 objects, each of which have the properties mentioned above.  Hm.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 please update your question to reflect the actual structure of `data`, or else nobody can help you. We had no idea that `data` was an array until now, and that makes all the difference.

Comment: Looks to me like this answer should work.

Answer (score 1):

info_date is a Number, not a String
change

```
f = _.where(data, {info_date : "2006"});
```

by

```
f = _.where(data, {info_date : 2006});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is nested within `data.properties`, so `_.where` won't find it. Your GeoJSON data structure is missing an opening brace so I can't be 100% sure I know your structure, but it *looks like* you could simply:

```
_.filter(data, function(d) { return d.properties.info_date == 2006; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all- per your suggestions I've tried  the following, yet I still can't console log (f) and get anything to show up.

```
function filterByYear(data){
console.log("filtering")
console.log(data)
f = _.filter(data, function(d) { return d.properties.info_date == 2014; });
console.log(f)
return f;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much do the same with plain javascript using [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), without underscore if data is an array

```
f = data.filter(function(d){ return d.properties.info_date === '2016';})
```

The return value of filter function is again an array. To get the first element you can just do

```
f = data.filter(function(d){ return d.properties.info_date === '2016';})[0];
```